# Has any crypto hash function been proven to be surjective?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/33633/6733) claims that "*it is not proven that all outputs of SHA-1 are possible*." Has any crypto hash function been proven to produce all possible outputs (i.e., to be [surjective](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Surjection) over the codomain of all possible numbers $[0, 2^n]$, where $n$ is the number of bits of the hash)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has any crypto hash function been proven to produce all possible outputs (i.e., to be surjective…

Not when looking at the practically used hash functions like the SHA-2 family, but when looking at the theoretical constructions we don't tend to practically use… the answer is "yes".

- #### "No" for practically used hash families like SHA-2

  At least, not when we're talking about cryptographic hash functions we practically use. Actually, the reason for that is pretty obvious if you think about it for a second. Quoting [a 2010 answer by Pornin at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659174/2432317):

  > … surjectivity proof for a random oracle requires an awful lot of computing power, substantially more than mere attacks such as preimages (2^n) and collisions (2^(n/2)). Consequently, **a good hash function "should not" allow a property such as surjectivity to be actually proven**. It would be very suspicious: security of hash function stems from the intractability of their internal structure, and such an intractability should firmly oppose to any attempt at mathematical analysis.
  >
  > As a consequence, **surjectivity is not formally proven for any decent hash function**, and not even for "broken" hash functions such as MD4. It is only "highly suspected" (a random oracle with inputs much longer than the output should be surjective).

  <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>
- #### "Yes" for more theoretical hash constructions

  The fact that hashes we practically use don't come with such proof doesn't mean it isn't possible to theoretically create such a hash function. For a nice example of such a construction with implying proof, [check Lindell's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54633/12164). (Btw.: I would call it an example of a Chaum-van Heijst-Pfitzmann Hash Function instead of attributing it to Damgård like Lindell does, but that's just an aside.)

  The reason(s) why we don't prefer to practically use such hash constructions is [a different question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54636/12164).

Answer (score 7):

The answer is YES for constructions of hash functions that are not used in practice. For example, there is a construction by Damgård that is based on the discrete log problem and works by computing $h(x_1\|x_2)=g^{x_1}\cdot h^{x_2}$, where $g$ is a generator of the group. If $h$ is chosen randomly in the group, then it is hard to find a collision in this function, unless you can solve the discrete log problem. By applying the Merkle-Damgård transform, you get a hash function that takes inputs of any length. Thus, this is a collision resistant hash function.

It is easy to see that this function is surjective. Specifically, $g$ is a generator of the group, so for every $h'\in\mathbb{G}$ and for every $x_2$ there exists a value $x_1$ such that $g^{x_1}\cdot h^{x_2} = h'$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is whether *any* cryptographic hash function is proven to be surjective, let me construct a hash function and show that it is

1. a *cryptographic* hash function, and
2. surjective.

Let's devise a hash function where I am the random oracle. For any 256 bit value you give me, I will give you back a 256 bit value (the hash).

In my drawer, I have a secret table with all the input and corresponding hash values that I have previously calculated. If the value is in there, I simply return the hash value.

If the number is not in the table, I have a (secure) random number generator that will generate a new random number from the set of 256-bit numbers that are not in the hash value column in the table, with a uniform probability distribution. I fill the table with this new key-value pair and hand the hash value to you.

Taken from Wikipedia, a crypto hash function has 5 main properties. Let's see whether they hold in this case:

- Deterministic, i.e. same input yields same output: **YES**
- Quick to calculate: **YES**, just need a lookup or a random number generation (though it is of course still impractical for other reasons)
- Infeasible to generate a message from its hash value except by trying all possible messages: **YES**, it is provably impossible due to the randomness
- A small change to a message yields a totally different hash: **YES**
- Infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash value: **YES** (in fact, impossible)

So far, we have only defined a function from 256-bit to 256-bit values. Let's extend this function to the same domain as SHA256 by simply taking the SHA256 value of any input greater than 256 bits<strike>, pass this value to the function as defined above,</strike> and return the result. **EDIT: Removed since it creates a trivial attack, see if you can find it!**

Regardless of whether SHA256 is by itself surjective, we can still prove now that the function as a whole is simply by proving that the subdomain of every 256-bit value in the domain maps to a unique 256-bit value in the image of the function, and considering the fact that the subdomain and the image is of the exact same size.

What we end up with is a cryptographic hash function that is provably surjective. Note that there is nothing in the definition of a cryptographic hash function that says it has to be stateless; obviously all "real" ones are for practical reasons. It is much harder to construct such a function that is provably surjective and as e-sushi points out, none of the ones in use have been proven to be that.

Comment: This is not an efficient construction (i.e., not polynomial time) so I don't think that it necessarily reflects what happens with polynomial-time constructions.

Comment: @YehudaLindell In regards to the input length N it has the same complexity as SHA256. The lookup + random number generation is only done for 256-bit values so the complexity of that sub-function in regards to N is actually O(1).

Comment: Several probs with your "I'm a hash function" thin. Most important: the table of stored values will quickly grow beyond feasibility of storage and handling. Furthermore, you're wrong when saying `Infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash value: YES (in fact, impossible)` as you're only handling 256 bits… which voids your `imposible` as there are only that many pidgeon holes to fill until you' end up producing a collision yourself due to the fact you've run out of space. And to put a tongue-in-cheek ending to it: you're a nice target for timing attacks as well as brute-force.

Comment: @TobiasBengtsson Looking again at your answer, it's not a hash function anyway since it requires state and requires a secret value.

Comment: @e-sushi A timing attack is only possible with a weak implementation. The table size issue is dependent on what the function is used for, some hash functions are used for a short time and then reseeded, for example [Python's __hash()__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). Regarding the brute force and pigeonhole issues, I'm not really sure how it is worse than SHA256 itself. Note though that I was sloppy when I wrote this and introduced an error, I've edited now but maybe that was the issue you referred to. In any way, I never said that this was a good algo :)

Comment: @YehudaLindell No "secret value" is required here - it's all just a stochastic process (algorithm). In fact, even if all hashes generated are published (think time-stamping) it is still a valid crypto hash algo, as long as the corresponding pre-images are not published of course.
With regards to state: I was also a bit unsure of this before posting this answer, but I couldn't find a definition of a hash function that excludes the possibility of a state directly or indirectly. Perhaps you can enlighten me?